# Where Do I put non ViewModel classes in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm not too sure what is the best practice for putting a non ViewModel class? It seems like bad practice to put them into the Models folder if they are not used by the views.

Should I create a separate folder or just leave them in there?

Comment: What's in them, logic?  Perhaps a separate class library project

Comment: Where you put something would logically be driven by what that something is.  There shouldn't be a generic repository for nondescript code.  Instead, for any given object, what is that object in relation to the entire system?  Similar objects can be grouped into a folder, into a project, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you should create another project named Repository or DAL where you can keep things la Dto or other stuff